# Find degree of polynomial satisfying given condition

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $$1+f(x)=\frac{f(x-1)+f(x+1)}{2} \forall x\in R$$
>   then find $n$.

**My attempt:**
I first started off by trying to prove $f(x)$ to be periodic, as I always do whenever I spot $f(x-a)+f(x+a)$ anywhere. It did not work anyway. Then
 I thought of assuming a standard function of degree = $1,2,3$. It failed for 1 and 3, and worked for 2, so I gave answer as 2. However, I feel that:

1. I did not prove that there are no higher $n$ for which this equation holds.
2. My method is not neat at all!

I guess there must be a much simpler method, can anyone please give some starting steps for that neat logic?

Comment: A polynomial is determined by its values on the natural numbers, for example. Given $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ this is a linear recurrence with constant coefficients. That means that you can find an explicit expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$, $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: Another approach is to write the polynomial in a basis that behaves nice with respect to $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. You equation is $\Delta^2f(x-1)=2$. Consider the basis $1,x,x(x+1),x(x+1),x(x+1)(x+2),...$. Make yourself familiar how this basis behaves under the action of $\Delta$.

Comment: If second differences are constant, it's a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: @Marja Suppose $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, how would I then find $f(n)$, since $f(x)$ could be anything = $x^2, x^3, x^4,..x^n$? I also don't get what you mean by "a linear recurrence with constant coefficients"?

Comment: @GaurangTandon You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) to learn what is a recurrence relation and how to solve it. That knowledge is quite useful on its own, although only one approach for this problem. The second approach I posted is more neat.

Comment: You might note in the future that the only periodic polynomials are constants, so there is no point in ever testing them for periodicity.

Answer (score 10):

The sequence of polynomials $$p_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)\qquad n=0,...$$ is a basis of the space of polynomials. Therefore any polynomial solution can be expressed as a linear combination of these $p_n(x)$.

If $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, then $$\Delta^2f(x)=\Delta(\Delta f(x-1))=\Delta(f(x)-f(x-1))=f(x+1)-2f(x)+f(x-1)$$

The equation we have can be written as $$\Delta^2 f(x-1)=2$$

Let's compute the action of $\Delta$ on $p_n$.

$$\Delta p_{0}(x)=1-1=0$$

$$\begin{align}\Delta p_n(x)&=p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)\\&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k+1)-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)\\&=n\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}(x+k)\\&=n p_{n-1}(x+1)\end{align}$$

Looks similar to the familiar $\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial x}=n x^{n-1}$

Therefore if $f(x)=\sum_n a_np_n(x)$ then we must have

$$\sum_{n\geq 2} a_nn(n-1) p_{n-2}(x+1)=\Delta^2 f(x-1)=2=2p_0(x+1)$$

Since $p_n$ form a basis, all $a_n$ must be zero for $n>2$, and $a_2=1$. The coefficients $a_1$ and $a_0$ can take arbitrary values.

Therefore, your polynomial has the form $$f(x)=a_0p_0(x)+a_1p_1(x)+p_2(x)=x(x+1)+a_1x+a_0$$

Comment: This is really elegant!

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Though how did you get $=2p_0(x+1)$ in the second last equation?

Comment: and ""Δ2f(x)=Δ(Δf(x−1))"" in this step, why did you convert x to x-1?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Since $\Delta$ is the forward difference, $\Delta[f(x-1)]$ involves $f(x)$ and $\Delta^2[f(x-1)]$ involves $x+1$. Using $x$ would involve $x+2$ which is not what you have in the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using the recurrence relation method: First, to simplify things (a bit), differentiate the equation to obtain: $$f'(x+1)=2f'(x)-f'(x-1)$$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$. Now, for $n\in\mathbb N$, define $a_n:=f'(n)$, so that $$a_{n+1}=2a_n-a_{n-1}$$ This is a homogeneous recurrence relation of order 2, and the characteristic polynomial is $$x^2-2x+1=0$$ with obvious root $x=1$ with multiplicity $2$. Hence, the solution of the recurrence relation is $$a_n=(k_1+k_2n)(1)^n \implies f'(n)=k_1+k_2n$$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, where $k_1,k_2$ are constants. Actually, by substituting $n=0$ and $n=1$, you get that $$f'(n)=f'(0)+(f'(0)-f'(1))n$$ Since $f'(0)\neq f'(1)$ (why?), the first derivative of your polynomial is a linear function on the integers, hence on $\mathbb R$, hence your initial polynomial was of degree $2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. It seems like I've not been taught this method yet in school. Can you indicate some resource where I can learn this topic? Thank you!

Comment: There are many resources online under the search terms "solution of linear homogeneous recurrence relations" or "solving linear recurrence relations". Generally they have it for order $k$, but in your case (and in most exercises/ examples) you will encounter order $2$.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHw7hAAjbD0

Comment: Yeah, why not...

Comment: Well, I was viewing this after that video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp4PWCPzeQs - in this he uses a method which is completely different. I used the method I learnt in the previous video - of using characteristic equations - I got a weird expression involving $\sqrt{5}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I do not know

Comment: @GaurangTandon : Would you be willing to share what characteristic equation you did get?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a general polynomial $g$ of degree $m,$ $m>0.$ Let
$$
g(x) = a_m x^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0,
$$
where $ a_m \neq 0.$

Then
\begin{align}
g(x + 1) &= a_m (x+1)^m + a_{m-1} (x+1)^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0 \\
&= a_m\left(x^m + mx^{m-1} + \cdots + 1\right) 
  + a_{m-1}\left(x^{m-1} + \cdots + 1\right) + \cdots + a_0 \\
&= a_m x^m + \left(ma_m + a_{m-1}\right)x^{m-1} + \cdots + b_0,
\end{align}
where $b_0$ is a constant and all the terms not shown (the terms in the "$\cdots$") are terms of degree $m-2$ or less.
We see that $g(x+1)$ is also a polynomial of degree $m.$
A similar calculation shows that $g(x-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$;
by induction, so is $g(x+k)$ for any integer $k$, although that's
more than we need to know for this particular problem.

Taking the difference
\begin{align}
g(x + 1) - g(x)
&= a_m x^m + \left(ma_m + a_{m-1}\right)x^{m-1} + \cdots + b_0 \\
& \quad - a_m x^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \cdots +a_0 \\
&= ma_m x^{m-1} + \cdots + (b_0 - a_0), \\
\end{align}
which is a polynomial of degree $m-1,$ since $m >0$ and $a_m \neq 0.$
That is, in general, where $g$ is a polynomial of positive degree $m,$
the difference $g(x + 1) - g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1.$

Let $h(x) = g(x) - g(x-1).$
Since $g(x-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $m,$ 
$$h(x) = g((x+1) - 1) - g(x-1)$$ 
is a polynomial of degree $m-1.$
If $m=1$ then $h(x)$ is a constant, so $h(x+1) = h(x) = 0$;
but if $m > 1$ then
$$h(x+1) - h(x) = (g(x+1) - g(x)) - (g(x) - g(x-1))
= g(x+1) - 2g(x) + g(x-1)$$
is a polynomial of degree $m-2.$

I have written the facts above in terms of some arbitrary polynomial $g,$
rather than the less general polynomial $f$ in your problem,
to show that this method of differences is generally applicable.
Now let's apply it to your particular question.

Consider $f_2(x) = f(x+1) - 2f(x) + f(x-1),$ where $f$ is the polynomial of degree $n$ in the question. It is given that
$$1+f(x)=\frac{f(x-1)+f(x+1)}{2},$$
from which it follows that $f_2(x) = 2,$
that is, $f_2$ has degree $0.$
If $n = 0$ or $n = 1,$ we would have $f_2(x)=0,$
which is a contradiction;
therefore $n \geq 2$ and $f_2$ has degree $n-2.$
Combining the two statements about the degree of
$f_2,$ the degree of $f_2$ is $n - 2 = 0.$
Therefore $n=2.$

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive solution, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Define $f_1(x):=f(x+1)-f(x)$, $f_{k+1}(x):=f_k(x+1)-f_k(x)$.

Since $f(x+1)−2f(x)+f(x−1)=2$, we know $f_2(x)=2$ is a constant, which suggests that $a_n:=f(n)$($n$ is an integer) is an arithmetic sequence of order two. It concludes that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree two.

Comment: "...is an arithmetic sequence of order two..." In an arithmetic sequence, $a_{n}=k+(n-1)d$, so, $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=d$ which is good but here $a_{n}$ happens to be _linear_ in $n$ and not quadratic. What am I missing?

Comment: An arithmetic sequence of order two is not an arithmetic sequence itself, but some like that it has a hidden one. An arithmetic sequence satisfies $f_1(x)$ is a constant, while an arithmetic sequence of order $k$ satisfies $f_k(x)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the given equation with respect to $x$ yields:

$$ f'(x) = \frac{f'(x+1)-f'(x-1)}{2} $$

In other words,

$$ f'(x+1) - f'(x) = f'(x) - f'(x-1) = m$$

where $m$ is some constant real value.

This implies that for all $x$, the points $f'(x+k)\;|\;k \in \mathbb{Z}$ lie on the line $f'(x)=mx+b$ for some $b$.

If $m=0$: Since $f'(x)$ is continuous, $f(x)=bx+c$ for some $c$, but substituting this function into the original relationship shows that there is no solution for $c$.

If $m\ne0$: Since $f'(x)$ is continuous, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}mx^2+bx+c$ for some $c$, and substituting shows that this function satisfies the original relationship when $m=2$.

Thus, any function of the form $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$ satisfies the original relationship and $n=2$.